# how call a TinyMCE plugin function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tinymce, rte

how can I call a tinymce plugin function?

```
 tinymce.activeEditor.plugins.customplugin.customfunction(customvar);
```

not working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> tinymce.activeEditor.plugins.customplugin.customfunction(customvar);

is the correct way to call such a function.
Be aware that `tinymce.activeEditor` needs to be set already in order to use it.
`tinymce.activeEditor` gets set when the user clicks into the editor for example.
Otherwise use

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id_here').plugins.customplugin.customfunction(customvar);
```

There might be another reason for your function call not to work:
The function you want to call needs to be defined like the functions `getInfo`, `_save` and `_nodeChange` in the save plugin (see the developer build of tinymce to inspect this plugin in the plugins directory).

The save plugin shortened here:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.Save', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
           ...
        },

        getInfo : function() {
                   ...
        },

        // Private methods

        _nodeChange : function(ed, cm, n) {
                   ...
        },

        // Private methods
                   ...
        _save : function() {

        }
    });

    // Register plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('save', tinymce.plugins.Save);
})();
```

You may call the `getInfo` function of this plugin using the following javascript call:

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id_here').plugins.save.getInfo();
```

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/plugins/save/plugin.js

Comment: This link is not up to date now because the updated version of the plugin use now an anonymous function in argument of the plugin.add() method

Answer (score 1):

Put the function you want to expose to the outside world in `self`.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myplugin', function(editor) {
    var self = this;
    var self.myFunction = myFunction(); // Put function into self!

    function myFunction() {
        console.log('Hello world!');
    }
}
```

Then:

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id_here').plugins.myplugin.myFunction();
```