# tinymce - Is it possible to call a custom plugin function from outside the toolbar?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

OK. i know may be this question has been asked before :

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897631/how-call-a-tinymce-plugin-function)

But my question is that how can i call a plugin function from outside button not from toolbar button.

I have added a custom plugins:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(e) {
        function customfunction(){
                    e.focus(true);
                    alert('Hello TinyMce');
            }
        }
);
```

[Check this on Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ngdaab/481)

and i am calling this `customfunction` from other function which is called when i click on `Custom Button`.
Like this:

```
function clickme()
{
   tinymce.get('textareaid').plugins.example.customfunction();

}
```

Button:

```
<button onclick="clickme()" >Custom Button</button>
```

But it is not working for me?

Am i doing right thing by calling `custom plugin function` with that way?

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to add a button with a unique `ID` to the toolbar and call the click event of the button. The plugin would look like this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(e) {

        function customfunction() {
                    e.focus(true);
                    alert('Hello TinyMce');
            }


        e.addButton('testButton', {
            id: "testButton",
            text: 'Example',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                    // calls the custom function
                    customfunction();
                }
            });
    }
);
```

Then initialise the tinymce editor like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "example",
    // show the button
    toolbar: "testButton undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

Finally call the button click event:

```
function clickme()
{
   document.getElementById("testButton").click();
}
```

Don't use the `add_filter`. The complete code form your tinymce fiddle:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(e) {
        function customfunction() {
                    e.focus(true);
                    alert('Hello TinyMce');
            }


    e.addButton('testButton', {
        id: "testButton",
        text: 'Example',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
                customfunction();
            }
        });
}
);

tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "example",
    toolbar: "testButton undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
//add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'example');
function clickme()
{
   document.getElementById("testButton").click();
}

</script>

<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea name="content" id="textareaid"></textarea>
</form>

<button onclick="clickme();" >abc</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

your function is stored in

```
tinymce.PluginManager.items[0]
```

inspecting the dom you can see that function. try to alert it